# Expect: How to use "ls -d filename" for full path name in expect?

Tags: scripting, automation, expect

I am trying to automate loading of image on the hardware using expect. For that I need to get full path of the image.

I am using the following syntax -

```
spawn ls -d $env(PWD)/build/image/bmxs.*bin
expect -re {(\S+)(\r)}
set imgpath $expect_out(1,string)
```

The message I get is -

```
spawn: returns {51875}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "(\S+)(\r)"? no
```

So, it appears that the spawn does not return anything.

I've tried various syntaxes, but no use -

```
send "ls -d $env(PWD)/build/images/final/nxos.*bin\r"
spawn "ls -d $env(PWD)/build/image/bmxs.*bin"
puts "$LS" ### where $LS is the command.
```

None of these work. Am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that

1. the image file is local - on same machine where you run Expect
2. You want the first file which matches the pattern

If this is so, you can just do

```
set files [glob $env(PWD)/build/image/bmxs.*bin]
set imgpath [lindex [lsort $files] 0]
```

On the other hand, the phrase "on the hardware" suggests that this image file is on some remote system.  If so, and you already have spawned a login session there, you need to `send` the `ls` command on the existing session and then `expect` the output from `ls`.  However in that case it looks strange to get the directory from $env(PWD)" as this will read the environment variable PWD on your local machine.